# How to Improve Middle-Click Sensitivity on Thinkpad X1 Carbon?

Tags: mouse, thinkpad

The drivers that came pre-installed on the Thinkpad Carbon X1 do not look like those in the [online help](http://support.lenovo.com/en_CA/diagnose-and-fix/detail.page?DocID=HT000611) and do not offer the choice of function for the middle-button. So, I installed those from Synaptics directly and those did not have the option either :(

After trying various online suggestions, [changing the TrackPointMode  registry key to 2214](http://johnbruer.com/2013/05/18/middle-click-thinkpad-synaptics-touchpad/) finally worked but I have to click many many times to get the middle-click to register which kind of defeats the efficiency provided by the middle-click.

The button-size is set to *large* in the driver but that makes no difference for the middle-click, only the right-click appears larger.

Is there a way to improve middle-click performance on the Thinkpad Carbon X1?